# Web api 2 dentro de projeto MVC. Como evitar que haja redirecionamento para a página de login quando o token não é válido

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api, owin

Estou fazendo uma API Rest em um projeto MVC. Nos controllers da API (`ApiController`) coloco o DataAnnotation `Authorize`, quando o token informado é inválido, ele detecta e tenta redirecionar para a página de login. Só que não quero esse comportamento na Api, quero retornar um erro 401, se possível com um objeto JSON informando que o usuário não está autorizado a acessar o conteúdo.

```
[WebApiAuthorize(Roles = Constantes.PERMISSAO_API)]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/controller")]
public class BancoController : ApiController {


}
```

Esta é a classe personalizada do Authorize

```
public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext ctx) {
        if (!ctx.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            ctx.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        } else {
            ctx.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente utilizar o Result para retornar com o status desejado.

```
public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
           base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```